# How can I add an IEnumerable<T> to an existing ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

Given an existing `ICollection<T>` instance (e.g. `dest`) what is the most efficient and readable way to add items from an `IEnumerable<T>`?

In my use case, I have some kind of utility method `Collect(IEnumerable items)` which returns a new `ICollection` with the elements from `items`, so I am doing it in the following way:

```
public static ICollection<T> Collect<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T:ICollection<T>
{
    ...
    ICollection<T> dest = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    items.Aggregate(dest, (acc, item) => { acc.Add(item); return acc; });
    ...
    return dest;
}
```

**Question**: Is there any “better” way (more **efficient** or **readable**) of doing it?

**UPDATE**: I think the use of `Aggregate()` is quite fluent and not so inefficient as invoking `ToList().ForEach()`. But it does not look very readable. Since nobody else agrees with the use of `Aggregate()` I would like to read your reasons to NOT use `Aggregate()` for this purpose.

Comment: I would consider this abuse of the the `Aggregate` extension method.

Comment: @Codor I share your feelings about mutable shared state. But I am not achieving a “cheaper” alternative.

Comment: Why not a simple for loop and add the items to `dest`?

Comment: @ckruczek Maybe you are right and that is the better opiton. But I was looking for a fluent way of writing it.

Comment: Indirection is often a bottleneck, escpecially with the LINQ interface. Without any discussion linq and IEnumerable is cool stuff and they are implemnted almost as fast as possible. But if you want to have full control without indirection then its better to rely on standard stuff.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't better off returning a new collection?  `ICollection<T>` is a slightly horribly designed interface because it represents something that may or may not be read-only. If it is read-only, trying to add to it will cause an exception.  A new collection and `Enumerable.Concat` would save you a potential runtime headache.

Comment: In truth, in my problem's scope,  the collection is of some type `T` (a type parameter of `Foo`) that is instantiated by `Foo`. See `Foo` as a `collect` method which receives the type of `ICollection` through a type parameter. I will update my question.

Comment: Side effects in LINQ are horrible.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Ok, I have already removed side effects.

Comment: `Add` has side effects, namely mutating the collection you're adding to.

Comment: @TheInnerLight Yes you're right, but without shared state I think is acceptable.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa I think it's horrible to have a side effect in a function you pass to LINQ. I *strongly* prefer pure functions, though I'm willing to make exceptions for unimportant/unobservable side-effects caching or logging. In your case the main purpose of that function is having a side effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<YourType> result = dest.Concat(items);
```

If you want a `List<T>` as result use `ToList`:

```
List<YourType> result = dest.Concat(items).ToList();
// perhaps:
dest = result;
```

If `dest` is actually already a list and you want to modify it use [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dest.AddRange(items);
```

---

**Update**:

if you have to add items to a `ICollection<T>` method argument you could use this extension:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> seq)
{
    List<T> list = collection as List<T>;
    if (list != null)
        list.AddRange(seq);
    else
    {
        foreach (T item in seq)
            collection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

// ...

```
public static void Foo<T>(ICollection<T> dest)
{
    IEnumerable<T> items = ... 
    dest.AddRange(items);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Personally I'd go with @ckruczek's comment of a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in items)
    dest.Add(item);
```

Simple, clean, and pretty much everybody immediately understands what it does.

If you do insist on some method call hiding the loop, then some people define a custom `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, similar to what's defined for `List<T>`. The implementation is trivial:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
    foreach (item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

Given that, you would be able to write

```
items.ForEach(dest.Add);
```

I don't see much benefit in it myself, but no drawbacks either.

Comment: Why not just add `AddRange` extension method for `ICollection<T>` instead of `ForEach`? That's make api much cleaner and would reduce operation overhead as well.

Comment: @Leri That's not a bad idea, but it's more complicated. The `AddRange` that's available for `List<T>` performs better than a chain of `Add`s (when possible). A custom `AddRange` you might add for `ICollection<T>` should have that same effect (again when possible). An implementation that unconditionally translates to repeated calls to `ICollection<T>.Add` would IMO be misleading.

Comment: Obligatory blog post by Eric Lippert: "foreach" vs ForEach": https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: @Chips_100 I generally agree with what Eric Lippert has to say but I'm not sure I'm convinced by that one.  F#, for instance, provides `Seq.iter` which is exactly equivalent to a `ForEach` method for `IEnumerable<T>`.  Combining lazy evaluation and side effects is pretty dangerous but not providing that method doesn't even begin to minimise the risks associated with that.

Answer (score 4):

We actually wrote an extension method for this (along with a bunch of other ICollection extension methods):

```
public static class CollectionExt
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Contract.Requires(collection != null);
        Contract.Requires(source != null);

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

So we can just use `AddRange()` on an `ICollection()`:

```
ICollection<int> test = new List<int>();
test.AddRange(new [] {1, 2, 3});
```

Note: If you wanted to use `List<T>.AddRange()` if the underlying collection was of type `List<T>` you could implement the extension method like so:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var asList = collection as List<T>;

    if (asList != null)
    {
        asList.AddRange(source);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient:

```
foreach(T item in itens) dest.Add(item)
```

Most readable (**BUT inefficient** because it is creating a throwaway list):

```
items.ToList().ForEach(dest.Add);
```

Less readable, but Not so inefficient:

```
items.Aggregate(dest, (acc, item) => { acc.Add(item); return acc; });
```

Comment: That `ToList.ForEach` is one of the most awkwards approaches. You're creating a  throwaway list just to be able to use `List.ForEach`. So this will enumerate the whole collection to fill another list. Then that list will be enumerated again to add the items to the original collection. I always cringe when i see this. It's one of the reasons why LINQ has a bad reputation in some companies.

Comment: I completely agree with you @TimSchmelter. That’s why I included in my answer the most efficient one too. But I will follow your alert and include that note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
items.ToList().ForEach(dest.Add);
```

If you dont want to create a new collection instance, then create an extension method.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> source, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            source.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can edit your code like this:

```
        ICollection<T> dest = ...;
        IEnumerable<T> items = ...;
        dest.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: Maybe `AddRange`? BTW, you throw away the return value.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz `ToList()` will create a new instance (temporary in this case) that will be later discarded by GC. I think it is not more efficient.

Comment: @UweKeim `AddRange` is just available on `List`

Comment: 1. `ICollection` has no `AddRange` 2. In any other short code we will create a new collection instance. => `.Concat` creates a new list, and so on...

Comment: @MiguelGamboa : if you dont want a new instance there is no other way than a for each list. But you can create an extension method which do this for you. Then you can directly call `items.ForEach(dest.Add);`